# Find 10 closest points in decreasing order

Tags: python, scipy, distance, nearest-neighbor, scipy-spatial

I am trying to find the distance between a point and other 40,000 points.

Each point is a 300 dimension vector.

I am able to find the closes point. How do I find the 10 nearest points in decreasing order?

Function for closest point:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
def closest_node(node,df):
    closest_index = distance.cdist([node],df.feature.tolist()).argmin()
    return pd.Series([df.title.tolist([closest_index],df.id.tolist()[closest_index]])
```

This command returns the closest title and id:

```
df3[["closest_title","closest_id"]]=df3.feature.apply(lambda row: closest_node(row,df2))

df2- pandas dataframe of 40,000 points (each 300 dimension)
```

How do I return the title and index for the 10 closest points

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just slice the sorted distance matrix for the top 10 nodes.
Something like this:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

# Find the query node
query_node = df.iloc[10] ## Not sure what you're looking for

# Find the distance between this node and everyone else
euclidean_distances = df.apply(lambda row: distance.euclidean(row, query_node), axis=1)

# Create a new dataframe with distances.
distance_frame = pandas.DataFrame(data={"dist": euclidean_distances, "idx": euclidean_distances.index})
distance_frame.sort("dist", inplace=True)

# nodes
smallest_dist_ixs = distance_frame.iloc[1:10]["idx"]
most_similar_nodes = df.iloc[int(smallest_dist_ixs)]
```

My assumption based on the word 'title' you have used here, and the choice of 300 dimensional vectors, is that these are word or phrase vectors.
Gensim actually has a manner to get the top N number of similar words based on this idea, which is reasonably fast.

https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/gensim.models.Word2Vec.most_similar.html

```
>>> trained_model.most_similar(positive=['woman', 'king'], negative=['man'])
[('queen', 0.50882536), ...]
```

For something slightly different, this is also slightly similar to the traveling salesman problem (TSP) if you want to get shortest paths between *all* points, and then simply slice out the first 10 'cities'.

Google has a pretty simple and quick python implementation with OR-Tools here: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp.

Answer (score 1):

As I don't know your complete code of have a sample of data, here would be my suggestion:

Instead of using ".argmin()" just sort your list by distance and then return the first ten elements of the sorted list. Then find their indices like you're already doing it.